# Check if variable matches a key in an object, then save the value of that key into a variable?

Tags: javascript

How to check if a variable matches a key in an object, then saving the key's value to a variable?

```
let variableToMatch = 'blue';

items {
  'red' : '1212121212'
  'blue': '5656565656'
  'green' '7878787878'
}

let variableToMatchValue = '5656565656'; <<< End result
```

I am tottally lost on how one would write code to do this :/

Comment: read about object accessors and bracket notation -> `let variableToMatchValue = items[variableToMatch]`

Answer (score 2):

```js
let variableToMatch = 'blue';

const items =  {
  'red' : '1212121212',
  'blue': '5656565656',
  'green': '7878787878'
};

let variableToMatchValue = items[variableToMatch];

console.log(variableToMatchValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
    let variableToMatch = 'blue';
    let variableToMatchValue = "";

    items {
    'red' : '1212121212'
    'blue': '5656565656'
    'green' '7878787878'
   }

    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(items)) {
      if(key == variableToMatch){
        variableTomatchValue = value;
      }
    }
```

Or you could do it like someone mentioned in the comments with property accessors:

```
    let variableToMatch = 'blue';

    items {
    'red' : '1212121212'
    'blue': '5656565656'
    'green' '7878787878'
   }

   let variableToMatchValue = items[variableToMatch];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` .

```
var objKeys = Object.keys(items);
console.log(objKeys);  // ['red','blue','green']
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys